# SQL insert and update doesn't update or insert all the records, only a few record

Tags: php, mysql

My php code:

```
    for($i=0;$i<num_rows($sql);$i++)
        if(isset($_POST['knight'.$i]))
        {
            $data=
            [
                $pm_id=$_POST['pm_id'.$i],
                $knight_id=$_POST['knight'.$i],
            ];
            mysql_query("update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='$pm_id' and `knight_id`='$knight_id';");
            mysql_query("insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('$pm_id','$knight_id');");
        }
```

when I use echo instead of mysql_query it returns:

```
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_1' and `knight_id`='K1';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_1','K1');
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_1' and `knight_id`='K2';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_1','K2');
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_1' and `knight_id`='K3';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_1','K3');
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_1' and `knight_id`='K4';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_1','K4');
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_2' and `knight_id`='K1';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_2','K1');
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_2' and `knight_id`='K4';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_2','K4');
update `project_waiting` set `chosen`=(b'1') where `pm_id`='P1_3' and `knight_id`='K2';
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_3','K2');
```

It runs perfectly on my phpmyadmin, but when I change echo to mysql_query it only affect 5 rows (both tables)

P1_1-K1

P1_1-K4

P1_1-K3

P1_1-K2

P1_2-K1

My full database

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
```

-- version 4.3.11

### -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net

-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 23, 2015 at 12:16 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.24
-- PHP Version: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--

### -- Database: `knightit`

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `knightit` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
USE `knightit`;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `admin`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `admin`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` binary(60) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `employers`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employers`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employers` (
  `emp_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `emp_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `coins` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `knights`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `knights`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `knights` (
  `knight_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `knight_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `email` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `coins` int(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` bit(2) DEFAULT b'1',
  `bio` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `message`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `message`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message` (
  `m_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `send_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `message_send`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `message_send`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_send` (
  `m_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `projects`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `projects`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `pro_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pro_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `emp_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `p_describe` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `cut` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `s_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` bit(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `project_milestone`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `project_milestone`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_milestone` (
  `pm_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pro_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `milestone` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `job` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `deadline` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `knight_amt` int(2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `project_waiting`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `project_waiting`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_waiting` (
  `pm_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `knight_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `chosen` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `project_working`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `project_working`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_working` (
  `pm_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `knight_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `submit` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `approve` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coins_paid` int(32) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `security`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `security`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `security` (
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `skills`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `skills`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skills` (
  `s_id` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `skill_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--

### -- Indexes for dumped tables

--

### -- Indexes for table `admin`

ALTER TABLE `admin`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `employers`

ALTER TABLE `employers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `knights`

ALTER TABLE `knights`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`knight_id`), ADD KEY `s_id` (`s_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `message`

ALTER TABLE `message`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `message_send`

ALTER TABLE `message_send`
  ADD KEY `m_id` (`m_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `projects`

ALTER TABLE `projects`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pro_id`), ADD KEY `emp_id` (`emp_id`), ADD KEY `s_id` (`s_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `project_milestone`

ALTER TABLE `project_milestone`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pm_id`), ADD KEY `pm_id` (`pm_id`,`pro_id`,`milestone`), ADD KEY `project_milestone_ibfk_1` (`pro_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `project_waiting`

ALTER TABLE `project_waiting`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`knight_id`,`pm_id`), ADD KEY `knight_id` (`knight_id`), ADD KEY `pm_id` (`pm_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `project_working`

ALTER TABLE `project_working`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pm_id`,`knight_id`), ADD KEY `pm_id` (`pm_id`,`knight_id`), ADD KEY `knight_id` (`knight_id`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `security`

ALTER TABLE `security`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`name`);

--

### -- Indexes for table `skills`

ALTER TABLE `skills`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`);

--

### -- Constraints for dumped tables

--

### -- Constraints for table `knights`

ALTER TABLE `knights`
ADD CONSTRAINT `knights_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`s_id`) REFERENCES `skills` (`s_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--

### -- Constraints for table `message_send`

ALTER TABLE `message_send`
ADD CONSTRAINT `message_send_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`m_id`) REFERENCES `message` (`m_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--

### -- Constraints for table `projects`

ALTER TABLE `projects`
ADD CONSTRAINT `projects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `employers` (`emp_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `projects_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`s_id`) REFERENCES `skills` (`s_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--

### -- Constraints for table `project_milestone`

ALTER TABLE `project_milestone`
ADD CONSTRAINT `project_milestone_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pro_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`pro_id`);

--

### -- Constraints for table `project_waiting`

ALTER TABLE `project_waiting`
ADD CONSTRAINT `project_waiting_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pm_id`) REFERENCES `project_milestone` (`pm_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `project_waiting_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`knight_id`) REFERENCES `knights` (`knight_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--

### -- Constraints for table `project_working`

ALTER TABLE `project_working`
ADD CONSTRAINT `project_working_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pm_id`) REFERENCES `project_milestone` (`pm_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `project_working_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`knight_id`) REFERENCES `knights` (`knight_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

Comment: you update then insert the same row ?

Comment: yes, I update the `project_waiting` then insert a new in `project_working`

Comment: Do you use the same user for PHPMyAdmin and your PHP-code? Your database user has sufficient rights for updating queries?

Comment: when I run it on SQL command from localhost/phpmyadmin. It runs perfectly.  I use XAMPP 5.6.8 , PHP 5.6.8, MYSQL 5.0.11

Comment: And your PHP code uses the same user? :)

Comment: yes, my PHP use the same user.

Comment: Could you please update your post with your database schema? :)

Comment: ok, I editted my post with full database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with combine all of them into one query:

```
insert into `project_working`(`pm_id`,`knight_id`) values('P1_1','K1'),('valueX','valueY');
update set `chosen`=true where (`pm_id`='P1_3' and `knight_id`='K2') or (`pm_id`='P1_1' and `knight_id`='K1') or(...);
```